# Using compareTo() method each time with different sorting property

Tags: java, android, sorting, arraylist

I am using the method `compareTo()` in order to sort an `ArrayList` of custom object named `image`, but in my application some times I need to sort the array according to specific attribute like `goodMatches`, and other times I need to sort the array according to another attributes or properties of the Object, but I cannot override the `compareTo()` methods more than one time for different sorts.

I have tried using flags attribute for Object but the problem is other attributes are of float type and I need to keep the method `compareTo` to return float not integer as `goodMatches`. Can any one help me overcoming this issue without the need of creating another object class, any help will be highly appreciated, below is my code of `compareTo()`:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(image compareImg) {
    int compareMatches=((image)compareImg).getGoodMatches();      
    return compareMatches - this.goodMatches;
}
```

Comment: You will need to create custom Comparators

Comment: Can you clarify this statement: "I cannot override the compareTo() methods more than one time for different sorts"? I'm assuming you're calling `sort` from different places in the code, so can't you define different `Comparator`s for each usecase?

Comment: @Sindbad90 the compareTo is already implemented when using "implement Comparable" such my case : public class image implements Comparable<image>{}, So I cannot write second or third compareTo for other sorting types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following `Image` class (use upper case for class names)

```
class Image {
    private int goodMatches;
    private float anotherProperty;

    .....

    public int getGoodMatches() {
        return goodMatches;
    }

    public float getAnotherProperty() {
        return anotherProperty;
    }
}
```

You can create a [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for each of your properties:

```
class GoodMatchesComparator implements Comparator<Image> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Image i1, Image i2) {
        return Integer.compare(i1.getGoodMatches(), i2.getGoodMatches());
    }
}

class AnotherPropertyComparator implements Comparator<Image> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Image i1, Image i2) {
        return Float.compare(i1.getAnotherProperty(), i2.getAnotherProperty());
    }
}
```

Then use the sort method on List to sort your list:

```
List<Image> images = new ArrayList<>();
// populate your list

// sort the list based on the goodMatches property
images.sort(new GoodMatchesComparator());

// sort the list based on the anotherProperty property
images.sort(new AnotherPropertyComparator());
```

If you need reverse order, you can do this way:

```
images.sort(new GoodMatchesComparator().reversed());
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but where I put this code In object Class or in mainActivity and I need the sorting to be always in decreasing order

Comment: You can put the Comparators in their own files, they are classes. And use the sorting wherever you need it. I will add a snippet for reverse order

Comment: Thank  you very much, your code seems to work, I will try it and return back to you

Comment: sorry for anoyying, but how can I return float instead of int? if I use float they said that type is compatible

Comment: use `Float.compare` instead of `Integer.compare`

Comment: but when I put public foat they said that incompatible since the original methods returns int

Comment: I made `anotherProperty` a float in the example to show you. Float.compare will always return an int.

Comment: Ok thanks, I highly appreciated your help Bentaye, I will continue my code as you said and see results

Comment: @wisam Welcome. Please accept the answer if it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of overriding the `compareTo()` try to make a class named `Comparator` which create a comparator(A judger who determines which object has higher priority) by passing an implementation of ICompare.

```
public interface ICompare{
   compare(image obj1, image obj2);
}
```

The Comperator class:

```
public class Comperator{
   ICompare icompare;
   Comperator(ICompare icompare){
      this.icompare = icompare;
   }

   public int compare(image img1, image img2){
      return icompare.compare(img1,img2);
   }
}
```

In conclusion, create as many Comperator objects you want by passing the implemented interface you want. Then use it to compare objects of type image.

I would like to tell you here that you can make use of Generics here but I didn't just because I wanted to keep it simple and clear!